# If equals doubles statement check

Tags: java, string

New to java, making a personal calculation program. Is there anyway to change the if(Block.equals("Furnace")) to include a check for "furnace". I tried setting "Block" to lower case, but it just breaks and doesn't calculate for either "Furnace" or "furnace".

Block is a text-field that the user enters into (either Furnace, or furnace), then if Block = "Furnace" or "furnace". Should I use an array to check where if it is something listed in the array, it performs the equation?

```
    private void CalculateCraftButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        double BToMake = 0;
        double TotalCraft = 0;

        String Block = BlockToCraft.getText();
        if(Block.equals("Furnace"))
        {
            BToMake = Double.valueOf(QuantityCraftField.getText()).doubleValue();

            double Furnace = 8;
            double furnace = 8; 


            TotalCraft = Furnace * BToMake;
            TotalCraft = furnace * BToMake;

            TotalCraftField.setText(String.valueOf(TotalCraft));
        }
```

Comment: Trying to get if(Block.equals("Furnace")) to also include "furnace"

Comment: You can use `Block.equalsIgnoreCase("Furnace")`

Comment: What about "furNace"?

Comment: Trying to have "Furnace" = "furnace", but able to type both as they have the same value and have calculations work

Comment: `if(Block.toLowerCase().equals("furnace"))`

Comment: `String Block` : it's a bad pratice to start a variable name with an uppercase. You should replace it by `String block`

Comment: Might I recommend reading [Java naming conventions?](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) It makes reading your code much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Block.equalsIgnoreCase("Furnace")`

Answer (score 2):

> I tried setting "Block" to lower case, but it just breaks and doesn't
>   calculate for either "Furnace" or "furnace".

It should work if you use the new `String` object returned by the `block.toLowerCase()` invocation :

```
 String block = BlockToCraft.getText();
 if(block.toLowerCase().equals("furnace")) {
    ...
```

`String`s are immutable so :

```
String block = "Furnace";
String newBlock = block.toLowerCase();
System.out.println(block); // displays "Furnace"
System.out.println(newBlock); // displays "furnace"
```

Answer (score 1):

String has a method **equalsIgnoreCase**, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))

you can do:

```
"furnace".equalsIgnoreCase(block)
```

and you should look how variables shall be declared in java (*block* instead of *Block*)